# R loop to subset information from a few subsequent rows and create new column

Tags: r, loops, text

I am still relatively new to R and I got this challenge.

I have a table (code below) in which the first column consists of names of managers and projects they have. Always after the name of manager (e.g. 'Tom Jones') his projects (e.g. '019200 [ytb] ppp') and other activities (e.g. 'Risk Management') are listed . Other columns represent capacity hours (`capacity`) and actual working hours (`actual_hours`) that manager spent on projects.

[Updated data frame]

```
df <- data.frame('Name'=c('Tom Jones', '0192000 [ytb] ppp', 'I-2020020 [BBB] Adm Valid', 'TENT DATZ 20204001 [ASS]','Risk Management', 'Andrea Jose Casteno','2040044 [Amaas] HHHHJ', '0291111 [inezzz] plmi', 'Training', 'Gerard van der Dike', '20200222+20203333 [Ttt ID/ZZ] HHH SSS DD +Dpp', 'Other' , 'R-20204444 [Res] Phhh Top SAA', 'Bill Gatea', 'Leave','2019xxxx [zzz] Aap ZZ'), 'capacity' = c(40,0,0,0,0,36,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,38,0,0), 'actual_hours' = c(44,12,2,20,10,40,30,0,10,43,20,10,13,38,20,18))
```

List of managers:

```
manager_names= c('Tom Jones', 'Andrea Jose Casteno', 'Gerard van der Dike', 'Bill Gatea')
```

I need to transform this table into the below output (picture below). For each manager that worked more than his capacity (`actual_hours` > `capacity`), I need to create a row in the new table. First column should be manager name. Second and third column show his `capacity` and `actual_hours`. Forth column should present short project names that manger worked on (exclude projects with 0 == `actual_hours`). The short project names need to be subtracted from the `Name` column - they are in the square brackets (e.g. BBB)

[image: output]

For now, I tried the below lines but I am stuck with how to subtract the information about projects (fourth column in the output). Probably a loop using the list of manager names is needed.

```
z=(which(df$actual_hours > df$capacity))

output_df=df[z,c("Name","capacity","actual_hours")]

y=which(output_df$capacity==0, arr.ind=TRUE)

newdf <- output_df[-y, ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(df, cumsum(grepl("manager\\d+", df$Name))),
    function(v) {
      if (v$capacity[1] <= v$actual_hours[1]) {
        cbind(v[1, ], projects = toString(gsub(".*\\[(\\w+)\\].*", "\\1", v$Name[-1])))
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
      Name capacity actual_hours      projects
1 manager1       40           44 ytb, ytv, COM
2 manager2       36           40   TYU, inezzz
3 manager3       40           43   TYUKKK, ine
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Thomas. Actually, the real data in the 'Name' column contain manager' name and surname so there is no 'manager' pattern. In the function, I see it rather related to the 'capacity' (i.e. if 'capacity' is =0 then ...) Also, projects that have zero hours in the 'actual_hours' should not be listed in 'projects'. Do you have some suggestions for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  After creating a grouping column by taking the cumulative sum of logical vector i.e. where the 'manager' substring is found in 'Name', then `summarise` by `paste`ing the extracted words within the square brackets, as well as get the column values of the `first` row with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Name, 'manager'))) %>%
  summarise(projects = str_c(str_extract(Name[-1],
              "(?<=\\[)\\w+"), collapse="; "), 
     across(c(Name, capacity, actual_hours), first), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  select(names(df), 'projects')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Name     capacity actual_hours projects     
#  <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>        
#1 manager1       40           44 ytb; ytv; COM
#2 manager2       36           40 TYU; inezzz  
#3 manager3       40           43 TYUKKK; ine
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Akrun. I mentioned already to Thomas solution that actually, the real data in the 'Name' column contain manager' name and surname so there is no 'manager' pattern. In the code, I see it rather related to the 'capacity' (i.e. if 'capacity' is =0 then ...) Also, projects that have zero hours in the 'actual_hours' should not be listed in 'projects'. Do you have some suggestions in this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JusT is there any pattern in the data which we can use

Comment: @JustT if you change the pattern to `cumsum(str_detect(Name, '^[A-Za-z]))` would that work?  I find digits starting in the other rows

Comment: The names are structured the way you described e.g. 'Tom Johns' but also 'Ben van der Dike'. 
Project names sometimes start with digits sometimes with a letter + digits, then there is short project same in [ ] and full project name in letters - both short and full project names contain capital and small letters (sometimes only capital) e.g. '11101 [Nama] Naa Maa', or 'R-2000 [Hor] Prop Hut' .
I need to also exclude projects that have zero hours in the 'actual_hours'.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: I could also create a list with names of managers, but I am not sure how to adapt the code then ...

Comment: In case of the list, rows between listed names would be equal to projects.

Comment: @JustT Please update your post with a new example that shows all the patterns so that I can test it. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @akrun. I have updated the post and now it should show all patterns. I also added the example of manager names list that could be used.